# Pure CSS checkbox appearing differently on iOS

Tags: html, css, dom, mobile, sass

I am trying to perform the notorious task of styling my own checkbox with pure CSS. I'm not actually against using Javascript/jQuery to get the same effect, but so far I have not found it useful. It's all working fine in the browser, I have a triangle (play) for the unchecked value, and a pause symbol for the checked. However, on phone it appears completely differently and is actually unclickable. I don't really understand why it's appearing so radically differently? Any tips would be really useful.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px 0 6px 12px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ffffff;
  outline: none;
  display: none;
  animation: pointer 0.4s infinite;
  cursor: none;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  width: 10px;
  height: 11px;
  border-left: 2.5px solid #fff;
  border-right: 2.5px solid #fff;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Every browser renders HTML input/controls differently. Some browsers do not allow you to adjust CSS that other browsers do allow. I have always created my own 'checkbox' overlay that toggles a hidden checkbox. This method allows you to have full control over your design across all browsers.

Comment: @Illdapt – Would you be able to point me in the direction of a post or site that demonstrates how to do that? I've tried overlays but I've found that it messes with the underlying checkbox functionality.

Comment: Though I'm not a huge fan of W3Schools, here is a simple example:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Answer (score 3):

Since browsers implement their own input stylings, the most consistent way to create your own checkbox inputs would be to hide the checkbox input with CSS, and use an HTML label tag as the checkbox instead. You can style the `<label>` any way you want and it will be the most consistent across browsers.

Using an [HTML  tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" style="display:none;" />
<label for="checkbox_1" class="custom_checkbox"></label>
```

You can find some slick example on [CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=custom%20checkbox&page=1&order=popularity)